# How to compute a new date, 3 days from the selected date and then compare the new date with the selected one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check if the date selected by a user is at least 3 days from today, and if it's not, the gets an alert message that the date must be at least 3 days from today, but I'm not getting it right.

Here's the my code so far

```
handleDateChange = event =>{
        let date = new Date(event.target.value)
        let date2 = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3))
        if(date.toDateString() < date2.toDateString()){
            alert("Start date must be at least 3 days from today")
            return
        }
        //alert (date2)   
    }
```

When I let `alert (date2)` run, it prints the desired new date, the comparison in the if statement is just not happening and I'm not getting any alert message from the if block. I need help pls

Comment: dont compare the date string, compare the dates. Also, use `console.log` to verify if date2 is correct or not

Comment: Could you please post what is exactly the value of `event.target.value` ? Perhaps you're not using an ISO standard for dates in that string. Also, use `.setDate` on another copy, otherwise you'll mutate the initial `date` varible.

Comment: Both your date values are exactly the same. You are moving the selected date three days into the future with `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3)`, and then you are creating a new Date instance with the _return value_ of that previous operation (which was `date`, _after_ you altered it, in milliseconds.)

Answer (score 2):

The setDate() method changes the day of the month of a given Date instance, based on local time and you are changing it for **date** instead of **date2**

**You can do it like this:** [code](https://jsfiddle.net/abhi5h3k/0zhsobv7/11/)

```
let some_date = '2021-07-20'

let date = new Date(some_date)
let date2 = new Date();
date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 3);

console.log(date.toDateString())
console.log(date2.toDateString())
if(date < date2 ){
    console.log("Start date must be at least 3 days from today")
    
}
else
alert(date2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), I think mutates the value. So in your case, **date** and **date2** both will be having the same value. Can you please check and confirm if both of them have different values?

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed out, both your dates are identical.

Date / Times in Javascript can sometimes seem a bit awkward, the reason libs like `moment.js` etc are very common.

But for your example, you don't need the overhead of a library, increasing Dates in JS is easier than you think once you get the concept.

There is also another concept you might want to take into account, is 3 days classed as 3 * 24hrs, or physical day, the reason I mention this is that a lot of countries implement what's called daylight saving, as such the approach you take might be different.  Also does your 3 days start at midnight?, for example if your at least 3 days, and your start date is mid day, so that mean 9am is not valid, or that 9 am the next day where we want to start from. etc.

The trick for all the above is first clone the date `var date2 = new Date(date1)`.   After this we just use the built in Date functions like  `getDate` / `setDate` / `setHours` / `getTime` etc..

So for the simplest 3 days, (24hrs * 3), <- daylight saving incompatible.
We can do -> `date2.setTime(date1.getTime() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

And for daylight saving compatibly we do something slightly different.
`date2.setDate(date1.getDate() + 3)`

If you want to make sure Days are based as blocks  00:00 23.59,  you can then mix this with `setHours / setMinutes / setSeconds & setMilliseconds`